# How to disarm/remove a trap?

Tags: gloomhaven

The rules (page 14) say:

> A trap can also be disarmed through specific actions to remove it from the board without suffering its negative effects.

I know of a single specific action to remove a trap which is the Thief's Knack ability of the Scoundrel character class. What are some others? (Jumping over a trap, stepping into a trap or pushing an enemy into a trap, are not specific actions to disarm a trap, so they do not count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinkerer's Tools - the top effect is "Disarm one adjacent trap".

Comment: There are other ways as well but not sure on etiquette on BGSE on posting things that may be considered spoilers for content not available at the start of the game

Comment: @StartPlayer I'm certainly interested in knowing them

Answer (score 1):

[Curious Gear](https://gloomhavendb.com/items/125) will disarm all traps within range 2.
I'll leave further research to those who want spoilers :)